# Bootstrap 3 Carousel Issue, blank screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web-deployment

Tried implementing bootstrap carousel into my website. The result I get is below. Thoughts? I don't think it is a CSS problem but I am not too sure. I have looked around and cant find a conclusive answer as to why my implementation is not coming out correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>
<link href ="WorkingFolder/css/bootstrap_custom/bootstrap.css" rel ="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-right">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href ="#">|X|</a>
        </div>

        <!--Navigation control-->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href ="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href ="Services.html">Services</a></li>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
    </nav>
    <div class ="container">
        <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>

            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                <div class="slide1"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>William Xavier Fernandez</h1>
                    <p>|X|</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">More     Detail</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="slide2"></div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Web Design|Bootstrap|JQuery|</h1>
        <p>|X|</p>
        </div>
        </div>
           <div class="item">
                <div class="slide3"></div>
               <div class="carousel-caption">
               <h1>View my portfolio of work above</h1>
               <p>|X|</p>
            </div>
           </div> 
         </div>

    <!--Navigation control-->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
</div>
    <div class="container">
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
    <script src = "WorkingFolder/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="WorkingFolder/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

[The result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TkYI.png)

`

Comment: It's not clear what the issue might be from your code/screenshot.  Your screenshot shows the Carousel loading properly as your code has no background image defined.  The icons don't seem to be loading properly and that probably IS a CSS issue (something is overriding their font setting)

Comment: Thanks man, the icons were a CSS issue I remedied it by going into the CSS file and commenting out a few things. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the bootstrap documentation it looks like they've got an `img` setting the slide background and you're using a div classed with the slide number...I don't know if thats the sole cause here but I made a fiddle where instead of using

```
<div class="slide2"></div>
```

I put in;

```
<img src="image.jpg"/>
```

and that's got it working so far as i can tell.

https://jsfiddle.net/at4x4w8v/2/